# Not able to extend screen on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics, intel-core-i5, extended-desktop

I just bought a LG Flatron W2043C monitor. When I try to extend the screen with my laptop Lenovo z50-70 (i5 8 GB RAM), it does not work; but duplicating the screen works. I don’t know why this problem is happening. I updated all the drivers like Nvidia and Intel graphics but this also didn’t help me.
Please see image. 
In this image you will see that there is no option for resolutions. 
It worked for one day and after that it stopped working.

[image]

Comment: Install the monitor driver [link](http://www.driverscape.com/download/lg-w2043%28analog%29) and try again to extend the screen.

Comment: @spike_66 it is showing I have updated display drivers

Comment: You should have an HDMI port on your laptop. Try to connect the LG monitor using a VGA to HDMI adapter.